# InvalidIndexError with melt function Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I have the following dataframe and when I apply melt function:

```py
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
df_rm_features_melted = df_rm_features.melt(
    id_vars=['id', 'date'],
    value_vars=df_rm_features.select_dtypes(include=numerics).columns
)
```

I get the error: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

```
id      date  factoring  lglc overdue_60  distress  max_dpd  tr_op
0288     12/1/2018  0       1       1           1        0       0
0288     1/1/2019   0       0       0           0        10      1
0288     2/1/2019   0       0       0           0        2       1
0288     3/1/2019   0       0       0           0        52      1
0288     4/1/2019   0       0       0           1        2       0
```

Comment: What is the source dataframe? What is the expected output dataframe?

Comment: @sammywemmy source dataframe sample  is the one I have shared at the end of the question

Comment: kindly add the expected output

Comment: Have you made sure the `dtypes` of `df_rm_features` correspond to the ones you listed in `numerics`? If not, then your `select_dtypes` will return an empty list. Moreover, I see you select columns from `df_rm_features_unprocessed` but you melt `df_rm_features`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the error I get from your code is `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. Probably because `id` is in the `id_vars` list and is also a numeric column, so ends up in the `value_vars` list as well.

To remove the `id` and any other columns from `value_vars` without having to explicitly specify either, use [`numpy.setdiff1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) with the `select_dtypes` clause:

```py
id_vars=['id', 'date']
wanted_vals = df_rm_features.select_dtypes(include=numerics).columns
canhave_vals = np.setdiff1d(wanted_vals, id_vars)
df_rm_features.melt(id_vars=id_vars,
                    value_vars=canhave_vals)
```

Output:

```
     id       date    variable  value
0   288  12/1/2018    distress      1
1   288   1/1/2019    distress      0
2   288   2/1/2019    distress      0
3   288   3/1/2019    distress      0
4   288   4/1/2019    distress      1
5   288  12/1/2018   factoring      0
6   288   1/1/2019   factoring      0
7   288   2/1/2019   factoring      0
8   288   3/1/2019   factoring      0
9   288   4/1/2019   factoring      0
10  288  12/1/2018        lglc      1
11  288   1/1/2019        lglc      0
12  288   2/1/2019        lglc      0
13  288   3/1/2019        lglc      0
14  288   4/1/2019        lglc      0
15  288  12/1/2018     max_dpd      0
16  288   1/1/2019     max_dpd     10
17  288   2/1/2019     max_dpd      2
18  288   3/1/2019     max_dpd     52
19  288   4/1/2019     max_dpd      2
20  288  12/1/2018  overdue_60      1
21  288   1/1/2019  overdue_60      0
22  288   2/1/2019  overdue_60      0
23  288   3/1/2019  overdue_60      0
24  288   4/1/2019  overdue_60      0
25  288  12/1/2018       tr_op      0
26  288   1/1/2019       tr_op      1
27  288   2/1/2019       tr_op      1
28  288   3/1/2019       tr_op      1
29  288   4/1/2019       tr_op      0
```